# Увеличение счетчика пока нажата кнопка JButton

Tags: java, swing

Нужно, чтобы пока нажата и не отпущена JButton, сработало увеличение переменной, потом после секунды удержания с задержкой (к примеру, 100 миллисекунд) продолжалось увеличение значения. Как бы это сделать?

Answer (score 2):

Можете попробовать такую конструкцию с `Timer`:

```
    Timer timer= new Timer( 100 , (ActionEvent e) -> {
        flag++;
    });

    butt.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {}

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            flag++;
            try {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Testframe.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            timer.start();
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
            timer.stop();
            System.out.println(flag);
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {}

        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {}
    });
```

---

Зажал кнопку на 5 секунд, вывод:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Так как `Thread.Sleep()` вешает текущий поток, можно пойти на хитрость и немного подправить метод `mouseReleased()`:

```
Timer timer= new Timer(100 , (ActionEvent e) -> {
    flag++;
});

butt.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {}

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        flag++;
        timer.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        timer.stop();
        if (flag < 21)
            flag = 1;
        else
            flag -= 20;
        System.out.println(flag);
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {}

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {}
});
```

Comment: Хммм все выглядит здорово но по идее последовательное нажатие кнопки несколько раз должно приводить к задержке вывода на n*2000 секунд...

Comment: Почему вы используете Thread.sleep(2000); -? получите текущее время в слушателе объекта Timer e.getWhen() - время запуска события +2000 и проверка на начало манипуляций с флагом...?

Comment: @PeterSlusar да, есть такой минус. Добавил еще вариант кода, он не вешает поток.

Comment: Я не за пк но в данной вариации кода не возникает вариантов что занчения от 2-21 недоступны?т.е автор должен учесть что в поле нужно класть currentVal+=flag;

Comment: @PeterSlusar почему недоступны? если прошло 2 секунды, когда переменная не должна инкрементироваться, и + 1 секунда еще, предположим, то в ответе будет 11 (сработает `else` в условии)

Comment: flag=1 а не flag+=1 меня смущает

Comment: @PeterSlusar ну здесь такая логика - флаг инкрементится каждые 0.1 с., если флаг от до 21 - значит он попал в период ожидания тех 2 с, и его надо убавить до значения 1. Если флаг от 21, значит он лишний раз увеличился за эти 2 секунды на 20, поэтому `flag -= 20`.

Comment: Логику я прекрасно понимаю.Моя ремарка была как раз к тому что flag это счетчик и автору не стоит использовать счетчик в первозданном виде а стоит добавить еще конструкцию которая и  будет получать+суммировать+добавлять данные в некий наблюдаемый  объект. И собственно эта это по той причине что в вашем коде переменная флаг не обнуляется и к примеру последовательное долгое нажатие на клавишу вернут вам сумму всех ваших нажатий (6 сек+пауза+6 сек=80) а вот когда нажатие происходит единожды(выполнить 81 результат счетчика =1)т.е или в mousePressed первая стока flag=1; или развить идею с flag < 21

Comment: Хотелось бы что бы без мыши это работало на планшете

Comment: @S.Oleg нет слов )

Answer (score 1):

Это должно кое-чем помочь:

```
button.addActionListener(e -> {
    while(button.getModel().isPressed())
        i++;    
});
```

Comment: @S. Oleg, вывод добавьте помимо инкремента счётчика, может чего и произойдёт.